# ABCPdf in linux container

Tags: linux, docker, .net-core, abcpdf

I want to deploy a pdf generator that is dependent on ABCpdf (.net core) on a Linux container. the docker image file will build successfully but when we run the container I have the following exception

[image]

any idea how we can solve this issue?

Comment: Hi @Mahdi, ABCpdf.NET is now ported to Linux as per my answer below. 
This question comes top in Google search results for "ABCpdf Linux" . 
I appreciate it this may have happened too late for your project but would it be possible for you to take a look and accept this as the new answer if you're happy that your question is now more appropriately answered? Many thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ABCpdf.NET has now been ported to Linux](https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/default.htm?page=source%2F2-getting_started%2F6-platforms.htm) as of version 13 and is currently supported on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

As ABCpdf has Linux-native components there are some pre-requisite libraries that need to be available on the OS. There are some pre-prepared [Docker images on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/repositories/abcpdf) and the Dockerfiles used to create these images [are also available on GitHub](https://github.com/ABCpdf-Team/ABCpdf-Dockerfiles) for you to roll your own.

There is a sample [containerized microservice API project here](https://github.com/ABCpdf-Team/APCpdfLinuxContainer) that may be used as a template.

Answer (score 0):

The abcpdf documentation [states](https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/3-concepts/6-coreandstandard.htm):

> There are variants of ABCpdf for both .NET Core and .NET Standard.
>
> These variants are currently for Windows only and there are a few features which are disabled because they are not supported by the .NET Core runtime.

Therefore you could run it in a Windows container but not a Linux one.

Comment: Still ABCpdf not supported in linux container?

Comment: [Still not](https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/default.htm). Probably NOT EVER. It's a **heavily** Windows-dependent program.

Comment: It appears this has now changed. The documentation has instructions on how to run abcpdf on a linux machine now. It's in that same link, on "Getting Started" -> "ABCpdf on Linux".

Comment: Amazing  I guess if demand is high enough they find a way